# Microk8s install on RPI devices

Tags: microk8s

I have attempted to install microk8s on 5 rpi units but on my master node cannot get the node to accept other nodes nor do I get a response when I try to list the pods on the cluster.  the command times out.

running `sudo microk8s.kubectl cluster-info` doesn't do anyting.
running `sudo microk8s.status retuns` that is not runing.
running `sudo microk8s.inspect` seems to show containers running.

I would attach the .inspect but I cant seem to do that. let me know what's files are needed to diagnose the issue and I will post them.

Thanks